# How to detect the hand user holding his device

Tags: android, mobile, detection, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

We are thinking about detecting the hand, user is holding his mobile device, right or left hand or both. As far as our knowledge we think this is not possible with 100% accuracy with the current hardware, we even dont think it would have an accuracy over 90% but if you try to achieve this with the available sensor data which most of the smartphones have today. How would you process those sensor data and how would you decide?

Our initial thoughts are,

- Checking horizontal angle via gyroscope,
- Deciding based on face recognition and the angle with eyes using camera,

If you ask why would you do such thing,

As devices get larger (such as samsung note-2, note-3), touching every side of the screen is getting harder which causes user experience/ergonomy problems. We think if we can detect this automatically with a reasonable accuracy we may adjust our layouts to serve better user experience.

Thanks everyone sharing your thoughts,

Comment: i was just wondering if u solved this issue somehow ? if yes please let me know how u approached this.

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on a good way! After I tested myself holding the phone, I noticed I tilted my phone to the left (holding it with my left hand), and tilting it to the right as soon as I held it with my right hand.

Therefore I think the horizontal angle is the most important data you need. The bigger the phone gets, the higher the accuray (because you need to tilt your phone more to type with your tumb).

I would suggest you to also read the vertical angle to detect, wheter the user has his phone on a table or something

Hope I helped you a bit :) And sorry for my english ;)